# PowerShell remoting works with local IPs but not with the public IP on an Azure VM

Tags: windows, firewall, powershell, azure, winrm

Host is a single Windows Server 2019 running as Azure VM, no domain, no AD.

To isolate the issue, I am trying to create `New-PSSession` to the host *doing it locally, using its local PowerShell*. My command works for host's local IPs 10.0.0.4 and 127.0.0.1 but not with host's public IP. The host's public IP is via Azure, so it is not known by host directly as an interface IP

My script what I used to enable PowerShell remoting on the host are 2 years old, and those enabling methods worked successfully, but not now on this new host. I did all diagnostics what I've remembered and also googled the current common knowledge.

**I am using password on the clipboard in both working and not working cases  to rule out mistyping**

My command **which is working**. Note I am establishing a remote PS session *to the host itself*, just for diagnostics reasons: (also with 127.0.0.1)

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName 10.0.0.4 -UseSSL -Credential myadminname -SessionOption $sessionOptions
```

My command **which does not work** is exactly the same, except using the public IP, note I am trying to establish remote PS session *to the host itself*, just for diagnostics reasons:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName 137.xxx.xxx.xxx -UseSSL -Credential myadminname -SessionOption $sessionOptions
```

> New-PSSession : [137.xxx.xxx.xxx] Connecting to remote server
> 137.xxx.xxx.xxx failed with the following error message : Access is denied.

**What I did as diagnostics:**

Checked the port is open with `portqry -n 137.xxx.xxx.xxx -e 5986` It says :

> TCP port 5986 (unknown service): LISTENING

Maybe I am wrong, but based on this I ruled out the connectivity issues, both host's firewall, both Azure
network security group rules are configured correctly. I stopped the WinRM service, and checked there was nothing listening then, then started and was listener, so it is definitely the running WinRM service who is listening.

I've also ran `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 137.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port 5986` from a remote client computer and it gave positive result:

```
ComputerName     : 137.117.142.253
RemoteAddress    : 137.117.142.253
RemotePort       : 5986
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 2
SourceAddress    : 192.168.1.1
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

wh

I've ran `winrm e winrm/config/listener`:

> Listener
> Address = *
> Transport = HTTPS
> Port = 5986
> Hostname
> Enabled = true
> URLPrefix = wsman
> CertificateThumbprint = 4F89xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> ListeningOn = 10.0.0.4, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx%3

I've also ran `winrm get winrm/config`:

```
Config
MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
MaxTimeoutms = 60000
MaxBatchItems = 32000
MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = *
Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = false
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = false
        CredSSP = false
        CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = *
    IPv6Filter = *
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true
Winrs
    AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
    IdleTimeout = 7200000
    MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
    MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
    MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
    MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
    MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

Comment: You get an "access denied" error, so the connection is obviouly working; this is an authentication issue.

Comment: I am using the very same user name for the working line, and password is in the clipboard to rule out mistyping. you are right. it seems as an autentication issue, but what? (btw we all seen misleading error messages.) I edited the question to make it more apparent, I was double checked everything before posting

Comment: Try enabling basic authentication (don't worry, you are on HTTPS). Kerberos authentication only works if you can talk to a domain controller, it will by definition not work from the outside.

Comment: Many thx for your interest in my problem. Yes I know that Kerberos is not an option, with my limited knowledge (which I really have being *developer*) i thought NTLM is playing, but now I see that no such in the report. (or is that the '*Negotiate = true*'?. What the earth is happening in the local, working cases then, (10.0.0.4) is also a mystery for me.  How to enable basic auth?

Comment: winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}

Comment: The very same. I've checked the setting, it is changed, also restarted WinRM service. Still Access Denied. Please see my other comment on @gsmitheidw answer starting with 'when I try that in a really remote machine, the portqry -n 137.xxx.xxx.xxx -e 5986 also says LISTENING, but I got simply a canned error message'...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, trying to summarize here.

- If you get no connection at all when trying to connect from a remote machine, then it's definitely a networking and/or firewall issue. Please note that being able to connect to the machine *from itself* doesn't necessarily mean you'll be able to do the same *from the outside*, because the connection can be blocked *anywhere* in the path from the client to the server.
  (Also, I suggest using [Test-NetConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection) for this.)
- If you get an access denied error when trying to connect to the machine *from itself*, you are most likely running into this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/accessing-server-locally-with-fqdn-cname-alias-denied; and yes, the behavior can vary wildly depending on the host name or IP address you are using for the connection.

Comment: Many thx. For point 1: Yes, but portqry -n 137.xxx.xxx.xxx -e 5986 also says LISTENING on the really remote machine  To point 2) I will check that DisableLoopbackCheck. Still the question remains, If I have connectivity to the port from the remote machine why it fails, when the server's WinRM config seems to be diagnosed to super OK.

Comment: Can you please try `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 137.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port 5986` from the remote machine and post the results?

Comment: I've tried it returned: *TcpTestSucceeded : True*. I've edited the OP too with that

Comment: Ok, not a network problem then.

Comment: Update: I've disabled via registry based the article you were referring with method: Disable the authentication loopback check and now it works on the the host to connect self with the 137.xxx.xxx.xxx. Thx. Of course it still does not work from the remote macheine, but at least we see that my diagnostics method was wrong, and generated noise in the process. The unability to connect on the host to to self via the 137.xxx.xxx.xxx was a completely other thing, and had no diagnostic value

Comment: How did you enable HTTPS? Which certificate did you use? Can you get it to work on HTTP? This looks like a TLS issue...

Comment: I've created a certificate for the server, so that is how https is enabled. On the client I currently have no http enabled, just https, the certificate is not yet trusted, so that is why I am using the -SessionOption $sessionOptions on connecting where the variable is set to $sessionOptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck. This (the very same seems) to be working when I connect on the server to self, then the server uses the very same cert for TLS and the client ignores the non trust state

Comment: ...meanwhile via group policy I've enabled http on the client (disabled basic auth) and tryed connect via http, ditto the same error.

Comment: I just created a WS2019 VM in Azure to test this and did the same as you: created a self-signed certificate, enabled WSMAN using it and connected to the VM from my PC with -SkipCACheck and -SkipCNCheck. It worked at first try.

Comment: Many thanks. Meanwhile I accessed an other *client* (Win Server 2016)  machine and from there it works, *using it as client*. So the issue is with my client, pretty insane. My client is a Win 10 Enterprise with both PowerShell 5.1.18362.1171 and 7.1.1, I've tried both, neither can connect. As we diagnosed the connectivity is OK, what on earth could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be to do with network profiles. Try Get-NetConnectionProfile and see if the connections on the windows machine are public or private under "NetworkCategory". This is public/private relative to the network connections of machine itself not public/private relative to Azure.

To change the connection:
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "yournetworkname" -NetworkCategory Private

Comment: It says: "*NetworkCategory  : Public*"

Comment: If you change that to private it would trust that network to be used. Public represents an untrusted network in this context - like a cafe public wifi etc. Public does not allow a number of things to be run by design.

Comment: @gsmitheidw this is correct in many cases, but here he's getting an "access denied" error, which means the connections get through but then the server is refusing access. Also, he tested the TCP connection to the public IP address and it's successful. This rules out firewall or network issues.

Comment: @Massimo, when I try that in a really remote machine, the portqry -n 137.xxx.xxx.xxx -e 5986 **also says LISTENING**, but I got simply a canned error message, *'The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests.'* I mean this is **not** the Access Denied message, this case...

Comment: @g.pickardou I'm confused now... from the question, it looked like you got the "access denied" error message in a remote machine. What do you mean by "a really remote machine"?

Comment: I got access denied, when I issue the command *on the very same machine I mean the host, where I want to connect. It is just for diagnostics*. Also just for diagnostics using the 127.0.0.1 or the hosts self IP 10.0.0.4 (which is only possible in that scenario), where I got the diagnostics result it is **working**.  The really remote machine means my office desktop machine. A bunch of contradicting diagnostics result, I am pulling my hair out